# Getting response from jsonurl

Tags: php, json

I am trying to get the response from a remote page using json. I need to get the echoed string from the remote aspx back to my php. When I tested my aspx file, it echo either **"ok"** or **"error"**. I need to be able to capture this string using php so what I did was to use json. Is my syntax correct in capturing the data? What happens is that $response always shows null.

```
$jsonurl = "http://ipaddress/Web.aspx";
$json =file_get_contents($jsonurl);
var_dump(json_decode($json));
$response = json_decode($json);
```

Am I using the wrong code to get the response?

Comment: What is the value of `$json` after `file_get_contents`?

Comment: echo response without decoding it `var_dump($json)` and tell what does it print?

Comment: it shows null if it is encapsulated in var_dump. Is it what I'm actually supposed to get? I was hoping that the response would be whatever the aspx page echoed.

Comment: You supposed to get some string.

Comment: `file_get_contents()` will **never** return `NULL`. You haven't followed either of the first two suggestions correctly

Comment: @Phil I think it's the var_dump that's affecting the output. I tried removing it and it works fine now.

Comment: @marchemike of course `var_dump()` effects output; that's all it does. But your question isn't about *output*, it's about the value in `$response` which you claim is `null`. You have been asked to show the value in `$json`. This will determine if the response from `Web.aspx` is in fact usable JSON

Comment: @Phil Oh yeah you're actually right. I just noticed it just now. Man I am really sleepy. I thought what it was echoing was the same thing. Will just close this question.